The result of my assembly language code is 0 and there's an error on division
I tried to make calculator using assembly language, here is my code:
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    greeting db 'WELCOME TO YOUR CALCULATOR', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
    menu db '1 - ADDITION', 0Dh, 0Ah, '2 - SUBTRACTION', 0Dh, 0Ah, '3 - MULTIPLICATION', 0Dh, 0Ah, '4 - DIVISION', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
    choicePrompt db 'Enter your choice: $'
    prompt1 db 'Enter 1st Number: $'
    prompt2 db 'Enter 2nd Number: $'
    resultMsg db 'The result is: $'
    buffer db 6, 0, 5 dup(0) ; Buffer to store input (max 5 digits)
    userChoice db 0
    num1 dw 0
    num2 dw 0
    result dw 0

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ; Print the greeting and menu
    lea dx, greeting
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    lea dx, menu
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Print choice prompt
    lea dx, choicePrompt
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Read user's choice
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    sub al, '0'
    mov userChoice, al
    call getch

    ; Print newline
    call printNewline

    ; Print prompt1 and read first number
    lea dx, prompt1
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    call readNumber
    mov num1, ax

    call printNewline

    ; Print prompt2 and read second number
    lea dx, prompt2
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    call readNumber
    mov num2, ax

    ; Perform the chosen operation
    mov ax, num1
    mov bx, num2
    cmp userChoice, 1
    je additionOp
    cmp userChoice, 2
    je subtractionOp
    cmp userChoice, 3
    je multiplicationOp
    cmp userChoice, 4
    je divisionOp
    jmp endProgram

additionOp:
    add ax, bx
    mov result, ax ; Store the result
    jmp displayResult

subtractionOp:
    sub ax, bx
    mov result, ax ; Store the result
    jmp displayResult

multiplicationOp:
    mul bx
    mov result, ax ; Store the result
    jmp displayResult

divisionOp:
    xor dx, dx
    div bx
    mov result, ax ; Store the result
    jmp displayResult

displayResult:
    ; Print the result message
    lea dx, resultMsg
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Print the actual result
    mov ax, result
    call printNumber

    ; Print a newline
    call printNewline

    ret

endProgram:
    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h

main endp

getch proc
    mov ah, 07h
    int 21h
    ret
getch endp

readNumber proc
    lea dx, buffer
    mov ah, 0Ah
    int 21h

    lea si, buffer + 2
    mov ax, 0
    mov cx, 0

convertLoop:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0Dh
    je endConvert
    sub al, '0'
    mov bx, 10
    mul cx
    add cx, ax
    jmp convertLoop

endConvert:
    mov ax, cx
    ret
readNumber endp

printNewline proc
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dl, 0Dh
    int 21h
    mov dl, 0Ah
    int 21h
    ret
printNewline endp

printNumber proc
    mov bx, 10
    xor cx, cx

convertLoop2:
    xor dx, dx
    div bx
    add dl, '0'
    push dx
    inc cx
    cmp ax, 0
    jne convertLoop2

printLoop:
    pop dx
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    loop printLoop

    ret
printNumber endp

end main

The menu is ok but when it prints the result it only shows 0 as the results in add, sub, and mul but when I tried the division it shows "divide error - overflow" and it doesn't show the resut. I'm only a beginner so please help.


when it prints the result it only shows 0 as the results in add, sub, and mul but when I tried the division it shows "divide error - overflow"

The reason is that your readNumber proc always returns with a zero in the AX register.

readNumber proc
 ...
 lea si, buffer + 2
 mov ax, 0
 mov cx, 0       <<<< Your choice of 'number under construction'
convertLoop:
 lodsb
 cmp al, 0Dh
 je endConvert
 sub al, '0'
 mov bx, 10
 mul cx          <<<< This does NOT multiply CX by 10, and always yields 0
 add cx, ax      <<<< This always adds 0 to 0
 jmp convertLoop
endConvert:
 mov ax, cx      <<<< This always moves 0 to AX
 ret
readNumber endp


The convertLoop is wrong in its use of mul cx. That form of the mul instruction multiplies AX by CX and leaves the widened product in DX:AX.
Better keep the result that is under construction in AX and replace that lodsb instruction (that necessarily has to use AL) by other instructions that don't touch AX:
 lea  si, buffer + 2
 mov  bx, 10           ; CONST (better outside of the loop)
 xor  ax, ax           ; My choice of 'number under construction'
convertLoop:
 mov  cl, [si]
 inc  si
 cmp  cl, 13
 je   endConvert
 and  cx, 15           ; ['0','9'] -> [0,9]
 mul  bx               ; DX:AX = AX * BX
 add  ax, cx
 jmp convertLoop
endConvert:
 ret

